# Letter frequencies: plot a histogram ordering the values PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, histogram, frequency

What I am trying to do is to analyse the frequency of the letters in a text. As an example, I will use here a small sentence, but all that is thought to analyse huge texts (so it's better to be efficient).

## Well, I have the following text:

```
test = "quatre jutges dun jutjat mengen fetge dun penjat"
```

Then I created a function which counts the frequencies

```
def create_dictionary2(txt):
    dictionary = {}
    i=0
    for x in set(txt):
        dictionary[x] = txt.count(x)/len(txt)
    return dictionary
```

And then

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_dict = create_dictionary2(test)
plt.bar(test_dict.keys(), test_dict.values(), width=0.5, color='g')
```

I obtain
[image]

ISSUES:
I want to see all the letters, but some of them are not seen (Container object of 15 artists) How to expand the histogram?
Then, I would like to sort the histogram, to obtain something like from this
[image]

this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For counting we can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object. Counter also supports getting key-value pairs on the [most common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) values:

```
from collections import Counter

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = Counter("quatre jutges dun jutjat mengen fetge dun penjat")
plt.bar(*zip(*c.most_common()), width=.5, color='g')
plt.show()
```

The `most_common` method returns a list of key-value tuples. The `*zip(*..)` is used to unpack (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458953/1189656)).

Note: I haven't updated the width or color to match your result plots.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't sort the bars of the histogram. I mean, I obtain the same result..

Comment: Not sure why it is not sorted for you. What is your output for `c.most_common()`?

Comment: Wow this is slick. :-)

Comment: This is the output of most_common: [('e', 7),
 (' ', 7),
 ('t', 6),
 ('u', 5),
 ('n', 5),
 ('j', 4),
 ('a', 3),
 ('g', 3),
 ('d', 2),
 ('q', 1),
 ('r', 1),
 ('s', 1),
 ('m', 1),
 ('f', 1),
 ('p', 1)]

Comment: Is `plt.bar(['a', 'b', 'c'], [10, 5, 1])` sorted for you?

Comment: @ikkuh yes plt.bar(['a', 'b', 'c'], [10, 5, 1]) because a b and c appear in order, but c = Counter("abbbbcc")
plt.bar(*zip(*c.most_common()), width=.5, color='g') is not

Comment: You can check `list(zip(*c.most_common()))` to see that those are also in order.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = "quatre jutges dun jutjat mengen fetge dun penjat"

# convert input to list of chars so it is easy to get into pandas 
char_list = list(test)

# create a dataframe where each char is one row
df = pd.DataFrame({'chars': char_list})
# drop all the space characters
df = df[df.chars != ' ']
# add a column for aggregation later
df['num'] = 1
# group rows by character type, count the occurences in each group
# and sort by occurance
df = df.groupby('chars').sum().sort_values('num', ascending=False) / len(df)

plt.bar(df.index, df.num, width=0.5, color='g')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit**: I timed my and ikkuh's solutions

Using counter: 10000 loops, best of 3: 21.3 µs per loop

Using pandas groupby: 10 loops, best of 3: 22.1 ms per loop

For this small dataset, Counter is definately a LOT faster. Maybe i'll time this for a bigger set when i have time.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it doesnt appear sorted. Why?

Comment: @alienflow I don't know, the code i posted works with the test data you provided. Did you leave something out when copying? What version of pandas do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using jupyter for python and version 0.22.0 pandas. I copied everything. Won't it be for using jupyter then?

Comment: Actually, I have jsut tried the same in PYCHARM and the same result :( This is a nightmare

Comment: @alienflow Is the picture above sorted correctly for you? How do you want the letters sorted?

Comment: Yes, I want to have it sorted like you, but I tried jupyter lab, pycharm and nothing seems to work, different scripts... It just appears like the image I have attached in the question

Comment: I just ran it in jupyter lab and it works for me with pandas 0.20.3 and 0.23.0...

Comment: It's really weird and I dont know how to solve it :( Could it be something related with the plotting library?