# Plotting list of tuples (both plot and scatter)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot as lines and also as points a list of tuples
so I have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

lista=[(0,1,3),(1,4,5),(2,0,2),(3,5,10),(4,3,7)]
#lista=[(0,1),(1,4),(2,0),(3,5),(4,3)]

plt.scatter(*zip(*lista))
#plt.plot(*zip(*lista))  #<--- this works
plt.show()
```

I followed the advice on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458953/4451521)

However, when I plot as a line it works but when I do as scatter, it shows only the first values (0,1) and not the second value (0,3)

How can the scatter also work to plot two series of data

Note: The first serie being the first and second value in the tuple and the second being the first and third in the tuple

This works
[image: works]

This does not work

[image: donotwork]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to split your list into two datasets and plot them individually

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista = [(0, 1, 3), (1, 4, 5), (2, 0, 2), (3, 5, 10), (4, 3, 7)]
xes = [t[0] for t in lista]
data_a = [t[1] for t in lista]
data_b = [t[2] for t in lista]

plt.scatter(xes, data_a, s=10, c='green', marker='s', label='Set A')
plt.scatter(xes, data_b, s=10, c='orange', marker='o', label='Set B')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) for further input variants of `scatter`.